# Slick Slider stop anywhere drag is left

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, draggable, slick.js

I wanted to ask if there is a way to move the slick slider more naturally like when we drag it, it either goes to the next slide and if not dragged much, it goes back to the previous slide. But I am trying to find a way like if I drag and stop anywhere, the slider should just stop there if it is in between two slides